# Example Stripe Backend: Build fail

Tags: swift, heroku, stripe-payments

im exploring the iOS integration with Stripe and I am stuck at the getting started page. I am at step 3 of the example iOS app from:
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios

I hit 'Deploy to Heroku' button from  https://github.com/stripe/example-ios-backend, input my secret test stripe key but it throws the following build error on the Heroku dashboard as so:

> -----> Ruby app detected
>   -----> Compiling Ruby/Rack  !  !     An error occurred while installing ruby-2.1.2  !       !     Heroku recommends you use the
>   latest supported Ruby version listed here:  !
>   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes 
>   !       !     For more information on syntax for declaring a Ruby
>   version see:  !
>   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions  !       !
>   Note: Only the most recent version of Ruby 2.1 is supported on
>   Cedar-14  !       !     Debug InformationCommand: 'set -o pipefail;
>   curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3
>   --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/heroku-16/ruby-2.1.2.tgz
>   -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed unexpectedly:  !       !     gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file  !     tar: Child returned status 1  !     tar:
>   Error is not recoverable: exiting now  !  !     Push rejected, failed
>   to compile Ruby app.  !     Push failed

I am not quite sure where have I gone wrong as I simply followed the steps. Anyone any advise pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project's `Gemfile` was set to use Ruby 2.1.2, which is no longer supported by [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes).

The project has just been updated to use Ruby 2.2.7, so you should now be able to deploy it!